# Installing libusb on windows for use with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, libusb

I'm trying to install libusb (not libusb-win32) on windows 7. I have to link it with Qt 5.0.1.  Here are the problems I'm facing

- In the INSTALL file in the extracted libusb folder, it tells me to cd to the current folder then run

  `./configure
  make
  makeinstall`

  But I got the error

> './configure' is not recognized as a valid command.

Googling this problem usually gives the solution as installing libusb-win32. However, I want to avoid that, as of now.

- In the libusb library, there were a few MSVC projects, so I built them. That did generated some .lib files. So I proceeded to link them with my Qt project. It recognizes the libusb.h header file but does not link properly. Here is my .pro file

  ```
  QT       += core gui widgets

  TARGET = Qt_libusb TEMPLATE = app


  SOURCES += main.cpp\
      qt_libusb.cpp

  HEADERS  += qt_libusb.h

  FORMS    += qt_libusb.ui

  LIBS += -LC:\libusb-1.0.18\Win32\Debug\lib\libusb-1.0

  INCLUDEPATH += C:/libusb-1.0.18/libusb DEPENDPATH += C:/libusb-1.0.18/libusb
  ```

My objective is to link the libusb library with Qt. Please tell me if I haven't 'installed' the library correctly or if I am linking it in a wrong way. thanks

Comment: `configure` scripts are for *nix-type operating systems, not Windows. See the instructions in the libusb INSTALL_WIN.txt file.

Comment: INSTALL_WIN.txt
no such file exists in the extracted library folder.
PS I'm using libusb-1.0.18

Comment: Why do you want to avoid libusb-win32

Comment: I'm trying to port a code into Qt that required CLR support. That code was written for libusb. I don't know how compatible that code will be with libusb-win32

Comment: I'd recommend using CMake if libusb already has CMakeLists.txt's

Comment: @paulm I thought of that too, but the package didn't come with CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: @AndrewMedico the file INSTALL_WIN.txt was present in the previous versions, its just not in this one. 
It tells us to build the library using the .sln files provided. I had already done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project file does not reference the library. You only provide a path where libraries might be found, but there's no reference to the libusb library itself.

What you're missing is something like

```
LIBS += -llibusb
```

You also can't have multiple project file statements on the same line. The below is an error:

```
TARGET = Qt_libusb TEMPLATE = app
```

It should look like:

```
TARGET = Qt_libusb 
TEMPLATE = app
```

Comment: do I have to add the following line to my .pro file
`LIBS += -llibusb`

OR 

do I have to replace the existing LIBS line with this one only?

Comment: @user3079474 You need both. The existing line tells the linker where some of the libraries might be found. The new line tells the linker what specific library it needs to link.

Comment: I guess it is linking correctly as Qt is able to suggest functions from the libusb library as I type my code. However, it still does not build. I receive errors like this ~\libusb-1.0.18\Win32\Debug\lib\libusb-1.0\core.obj):-1: error: undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'~

Comment: The above error is because I'm using the MinGW version of Qt while the libusb library was compiled using MSVC++. As pointed out by many forums and posts on the internet; MSVC++ and MinGW compiled libraries DO NOT mix well

Comment: @user3079474 "Qt is able to suggest functions" Qt is an application development framework, it doesn't suggest anything. The suggestions come from Qt Creator, an IDE. Qt Creator and Qt are two separate projects, it just so happens that the former is useful to develop the latter. Creator uses the *source code*, not the binary libraries, so you can get perfectly valid code completion while having a project that won't link. Heck, you can get good code completion without having any implementation of the interface you're trying to use.